# What is the correct way to stop the nagios ndo2db daemon?

Tags: nagios

What is the correct way to kill Nagios's `ndo2db` daemon?

When I shutdown `nagios` and `ndo2db` I do the following:

`/etc/init.d/nagios stop`
`/etc/init.d/ndo2db stop`

and I see the following in `nagios.log`:

```
[1311865619] Caught SIGTERM, shutting down...
[1311865619] Successfully shutdown... (PID=12422)
[1311865619] ndomod: Shutdown complete.
[1311865619] Event broker module '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o' deinitialized successfully.
```

However `/etc/init.d/ndo2db stop` outputs the following message to the console:

> *ndo2db was not running... could not stop*

If I do `ps -ax | grep nagios` I still see a ndo2db process running:

`12381 ? Ss 0:00 /usr/local/nagios//bin/ndo2db -c /usr/local/nagios//etc/ndo2db.cfg`

Which I then have to manually kill before restarting ndo2db, otherwise I get:

```
[root@nag01 nagios]# /etc/init.d/ndo2db start
Starting ndo2db:Could not bind socket: Address already in use
 done.
[root@nag01 nagios]#
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

I'm running:

- Nagios 3.2.3 built from source
- NDO Utils 1.4b9 built from source
- Centreon 2.2.1 Stable
- Centos 5.5 x64
- MySQL 5.5 x64

**Update:**

One of the odd(?) this I've noticed is that when ndo2db and nagios are running I see two instances of ndo2db:

```
12753 ? Ss 0:00 /usr/local/nagios//bin/ndo2db -c /usr/local/nagios//etc/ndo2db.cfg
12792 ? S  0:00 /usr/local/nagios//bin/ndo2db -c /usr/local/nagios//etc/ndo2db.cfg
```

Is this normal? If so then my guess is that the `stop` part of the `init.d` script is only killing one process?

Comment: _I've noticed is that when ndo2db and nagios are running I see two instances of ndo2db_: one process is forked by Nagios. 

Also post the `stop` function of `ndo2db` init script.

Comment: @quanta - I found the culprit, have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit - it was Centreon's config file builder.

`ndo2db` has a `lock_file` setting which is missing from the Centreon config UI.

When Centreon generates the config files it also generates `ndo2db.cfg` - but without the `lock_file` configuration value.

There's an open issue about this:

> [No lock_file field in Configuration - Centreon - ndo2db.cfg](http://forge.centreon.com/issues/1086)

Having spelunked the source code, when `ndo2db` daemonises and if there isn't a `lock_file` setting then it ignores this and carries on and no lock file is written containing the PID.

This of course means that the `stop` function in the init script won't be able to identify the ndo2db process id so it can be killed.

**Update:**

To resolve this issue I manually added a new column to the `cfg_ndo2db` table in the `centreon` database:

```
ALTER TABLE `cfg_ndo2db`
    ADD COLUMN `lock_file` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

I then populated it with the path of my ndo2db lock file:

```
UPDATE `cfg_ndo2db` SET `lock_file`='/usr/local/nagios/var/ndo2db.lock' WHERE `id`=1;
```

This will force centreon to write the `lock_file` setting each time the config is generated. This also appears to survive upgrades as well, though I'd always check the database upgrade scripts to ensure this doesn't sneak in as an undocumented fix.

Comment: Somehow this issue is now "won't be fixed". I wonder what to do - adding lock_file every time is irritating as hell.

Comment: @Jehy - see my update

Comment: Yup, I found simular workaround in this enchantment request https://forge.centreon.com/issues/4244 - and it also has patches for php and ihtml centreon files (forms and templates, as far as I see).

Comment: @Jehy - good find. I spelunked the code to see how the config was written out and discovered it was enough to just add the `lock_file` column due to the way that each column maps one to one with the ndo2db config key/val pairs. The only problem with applying those patches is that you're going to have to remember this when you come to upgrade and re-apply. I have my own mod I keep needing to manually slot back in each time I upgrade: https://forge.centreon.com/issues/2575  - it's a minor inconvenience though.